# Partitioning data into features/labels and train/test after reading from csv file

Tags: data-mining, pandas, linear-regression

I need to read data from a CSV file and then the first partition that data into features and labels and then into the training and testing set. However, there are several issues cropping up again and again. Below is the code I tried with error,

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'mon' 
on line 
Y: train_y})
```

The code for Linear Regression:-

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

learning_rate = 0.01
training_epochs = 1000
display_step = 50

data = pd.read_csv('forestfires.csv')
y = data.temp
x = data.drop('temp', axis=1)

train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(x, y,test_size=0.2)
n_samples = train_x.shape[0]
n_features = train_x.shape[1]

X = tf.placeholder('float', [None, n_features])
Y = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 1])

# Model weights.
W = tf.Variable(np.random.randn(n_features, 1), dtype='float32')
b = tf.Variable(np.random.randn(1), dtype='float32')

# Construct linear model.
prediction = tf.matmul(X, W) + b
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(prediction - Y, 2))/(2 * n_samples)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)

# Start training.
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        for (x, y) in zip(train_x, train_y):
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: train_x,
                                           Y: train_y})
            # Display logs per epoch step.
            if (epoch + 1) % display_step == 0:
                c = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={X: train_x,
                                              Y: train_y})
                print ('Epoch:', '%04d' % (epoch+1), 'cost=','{:.9f}'.format(c), \
                       'W=', sess.run(W), 'b=', sess.run(b))
    print ('Training Done!')
    training_cost = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={X: train_x,
                                              Y: train_y})
    print ('Training cost=', training_cost, 'W=', sess.run(W), 'b=', sess.run(b), '\n')
    # Graphic display.
    plt.plot(train_x, train_y, 'ro', label='Original data')
    plt.plot(train_x, sess.run(W) * train_x + sess.run(b), label='Fitted line')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Could anyone help me with reading data properly in a rather general way? Snapshot of the data:-

[image]

Comment: Add a snapshot of the data!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how your data is but `y = data.temp` may be a Series containing the string values which should be cast to float values. Try to change it to the following alternative.

> y = data.temp.astype(float)

Comment: Or maybe they are cats which need to be transformed..

Comment: Where did you see cats?!

Comment: Cats -> Categories/Strings maybe.. Sorry for the shorthand..

Answer (score 0):

So, the question is to understand this ValueError that you are getting.

This error I believe is referring to your `month` column, which I presume you are using a feature for this network. If so, as this is a categorical variable, you will need to change this into a one-hot encoding representation (https://machinelearningmastery.com/why-one-hot-encode-data-in-machine-learning/), because the model cannot interpret the string, hence the ValueError.